# Why doesn't the JS spread operator work with Flow exact typing

Tags: javascript, flowtype

When I define a type using Flow and then use the spread operator to process it, why does Flow consider it an inexact match if the incoming parameter is of type A and the output is of type A (and the modified value is a property of A).

For example, this fails:

```
type A = {|
  attrib1: string,
  attrib2: string
|};

const processA = (a: A) : A => {
  return {...a, attrib2: 'hello' };
}
```

Comment: it can be simplified to: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCYAvGAN4A+YAhgFxgDO6ATgJYB2A5mBQL6oBjOOyY16RUmTpgA5AA8Z-ISPRhm4kuQB0O6ryA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a long standing bug, but is just (8 days ago) getting some commits!

see https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2405

The issue can be reduced to:

```
/* @flow */
type A = {| a: string |}
const a: A = {a: 'x'}
const r: A = {...a}
```

Trying this against master is now working, but not 0.69.0

- master: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCYAvGAN4A+YAhgFxgDO6ATgJYB2A5mBQL6oBjOOyY16RUmTpgA5AA8Z-ISPRhm4kuQB0O6ryA
- 0.69.0: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCYAvGAN4A+YAhgFxgDO6ATgJYB2A5mBQL6oBjOOyY16RUmTpgA5AA8Z-ISPRhm4kuQB0O6ryA

Comment: as a tmp workaround, replace `{...a}` with `Object.assign(def, {...a})` in the 0.69.0 example and it will pass.. though requires `const def={a: 'x'}` as default/base object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the github issue mentioned in previous answer, I'll deal with my problem the following way (until I can move to newer Flow version):

```
type _A = {
  attrib1: string,
  attrib2: string
};

type A = _A & $Shape<_A>;

const processA = (a: A) : A => {
  return {...a, attrib2: 'hello' };
}
```

Reinterpreting this for the simplified example provided, it would look as follows:

```
/* @flow */
type _A = { a: string }
type A = _A & $Shape<_A>;
const a: A = {a: 'x'}
const r: A = {...a}
```